# My async function returns Promise<void> instead of Promise<File>

Tags: arrays, typescript, promise

I have `downLoadFile` function that returns `Promise<File>` and `downloadFiles` that asynchronously calls it multiple times.

```
  async downloadFile(id: number, name: string): Promise<File> {
    return new Promise<File>((resolve, reject) => {
      axios({
        url: `/file/${id}`,
        method: "GET",
        responseType: "blob",
      })
        .then((response) => {
          const file = new File([response.data], name);
          resolve(file);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  }
```

```
  async downloadFiles() {
    const res = await Promise.all([
      this.view1 ? this.downloadFile(this.view1.id, this.view1?.name) : null,
      this.view2 ? this.downloadFile(this.view2.id, this.view2?.name) : null,
      this.view3 ? this.downloadFile(this.view3.id, this.view3?.name) : null,
      this.extra_photos.map(async (photo) => {
        await this.downloadFile(photo.id, photo.name);//Promise<void>
      }),
    ]);
    //const a = await Promise.all(
    //  this.extra_photos.map(async (photo) => {
    //    await this.downloadFile(photo.id, photo.name);
    //  })
    //); void[]
    this.fileView1 = res[0] ?? undefined; //File | undefined
    this.fileView2 = res[1] ?? undefined; //File | undefined
    this.fileView3 = res[2] ?? undefined; //File | undefined
    this.filesExtraPhoto = res[3]; //Type 'Promise<void>[]' is not assignable to type 'File[]'.
  }
```

But when I call `downloadFile` in `this.extra_photos.map`, which inside of `Promise.all`, it returns `Promise<void>`, not `File`.

Then I rewrote my code to this, but got the same issue:

```
  async downloadFile(id: number, name: string): Promise<File> {
    const file = await axios({
      url: `/file/${id}`,
      method: "GET",
      responseType: "blob",
    });
    return new File([file.data], name);
  }
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how promises work with async await. I came up with my version here but haven't tested

https://gist.github.com/jrgleason/eeed880f430dfc75ccd4330645c9109f

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your option. It will help me better understand how to work with Promise and await.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! Your rewritten `downloadFile` is much better.

Comment: @Bergi, yes, i agree that rewritten variant much better and cleaner, than first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either add a `return` to your `map` callback or remove the braces. It is not currently returning a value. So all it is doing is `await` ing.

You also need to wrap the `.map()` in a `Promise.all` since it will return an array of promises. And what you want is a promise for an array.

```js
Promise.all(this.extra_photos.map(async (photo) => {
    return await this.downloadFile(photo.id, photo.name);
})),
```

```js
Promise.all(this.extra_photos.map(async (photo) =>
    await this.downloadFile(photo.id, photo.name)
)),
```